# Radeon error atombios stuck in loop

Tags: drivers, radeon, 17.10, amd-graphics

The screen goes blank and shows logs me out immediately a while after using multiple monitors.

`dmesg` shows:

```
[33786.908877] [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
[33786.908901] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 6DD2 (len 254, WS 0, PS 4) @ 0x6DE0
[33786.908910] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 673E (len 78, WS 12, PS 8) @ 0x6777
```

`lspci | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun 
XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev 83)
```

[This post](http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Kubuntu_16.10:_Radeon_error_atombios_stuck_in_loop) explains exactly my situation. But I don't have `/etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf` file.

Answer (score 5):

I get the same error with the amdgpu driver. But my computer completely freezes and I have to hard reset it.
If you do not need the AMD GPU, you can blacklist the radeon (or amdgpu) module. It fixes the error but then the AMD GPU cannot be used.

Just create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` (I usually call it blacklist.conf) and add `blacklist radeon` (or `amdgpu`).

To check if it was really disabled, you can run `lsmod | grep radeon`. It should not display anything.

Comment: I chose this method with `modprobe.blacklist=radeon` in kernel boot parameter (grub). Other kernel boot parameters worked too : `nomodeset=1` ; `acpi=off` ; `radeon.modeset=0`.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, I remove the `tlp` package by running

```
sudo apt remove tlp
```

Comment: This saved my day.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but tlp is a tool for power saving. Simply removing it doesn't sound like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with my mother's laptop. Was updating without a problem for years.

`lspci | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` shows:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470]
```

tlp is not installed in the sytem. And I don't have /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf

Booting from the old 4.4 kernel gave no problem. But 4.15.0-32 did

I tried adding bootflags `radeon.drm=0`
without result. `radeon: unknown parameter 'drm' ignored`

I was successfull using the blunt axe approach by disabling all powermanagement with `acpi=off apm=off`

But ended up using the previous kernel by adding `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"` to grub.conf (see http://techadminblog.com/boot-previous-kernel-version-ubuntu-16-04/ for more info

This is how you add the bootflags in grub.conf

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash debug --verbose acpi=off apm=off"
```

IMPORTANT!
after editing grub.conf you have to run `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Comment: Yes, it does. It provides 2 ways to solve the problem in my case. 
I deleted the question in the end asking if someone knows a better way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case disabling radeon power management solved the problem ( turning off acpi prevented trackpad from working ):

1. Edit `'/etc/default/grub'` and add `'radeon.runpm=0'` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable, it will look something like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... quiet radeon.runpm=0"
   ```
2. Update Grub with:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot your computer.

Comment: if you have `[drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed` line in your `dmesg`, this should help as it did for me

Answer (score 0):

I Had a lot of trouble with this.
The last screen message was "switching to amdgpudrmfb from EFI VGA"
But after login with ssh and dmesg I've got the same of you "error atombios stuck in loop"

My goal was to activate amdgpu driver instead of radeon
So the kernel params that worked on grub was:

```
amdgpu.runpm=0 amdgpu.dpm=0 amdgpu.dc=0 radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1
```

I have kernel 5.4.0-40-lowlatency
Under Ubuntu 20.04
And my Video is an Radeon R9 280x, and from this wiki https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMDGPU

My firmware is the TAHITI
I Hope this can save someone else hours!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution for REHL. It worked for me. The solution is to blacklist the radeon module. For ubuntu some of the commands might different.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41278

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was already reported long time back to Kernel.org here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51381.

The solution is to add `radeon.runpm=0` flag to the kernel boot options.

Cheers