# How do I restore my GUI? No tty, gdm3, or HDMI

Tags: graphics, gdm, tty, tlp

All the graphics-related functionality of my Ubuntu installation is corrupted. I have several problems but I think the root cause of all them maybe the same. Here are my problems:

- I can't switch to tty terminals. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f[1-12]</kbd> just freezes my machine and I need to hard reboot.
- I can't activate `gdm3`. When I do so, I just get login loop and need to go back to `lightdm`.
- attach/detach HDMI freezes my machine and I need to hard reboot it.

Edit: I checked log with `journalctl -b -1 -x` and found this error:

```
*ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
```

PS: I have Intel HD graphics + AMD Graphics on my notebook.

Comment: If you're runnung a recent version of Ubuntu, `journalctl -b -1 -x` will show you all the log messages for the previous boot (the last one that crashed). Start there.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you, I followed your instruction and found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I have guessed the solution to all my problems was same: I removed `tlp` package and now I'm doing fine.

Of course the credits goes to [Kostas Maistrelis](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035746/221566)