# Atombios stuck in loop - after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, radeon

After upgrading from 16.04.5 to 18.04.01

HP Tower - 550-276na (N9C09EA#ABU)

Was working fine on 16.04.5

- Had issues with ppa - uninstalled with ppa-purge (was just php)
- Also had to disable secure boot - then re-install

  sudo apt-get install  linux-signed-generic shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed fwupdate-signed

**BUT now get error**

*ERROR Atombios stuck in loop for more than 5 secs aborting
And machine monitor gets stuck in boot - i.e. cannot login.

***How can I get the Radeon card working on 18.04?***

Many thanks

Mark

- [Radeon error atombios stuck in loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978525/radeon-error-atombios-stuck-in-loop) 
  -- This seems to mention removing tlp ??? - which makes no sense
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics - tried vgaswitcheroo, which I can start, but doesn't seem to work.

### lspci -k shows

```
bamboo@ubuntu ~ $ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H SMBus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

### Kern.log shows

```
Oct  8 20:40:39 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.169328] [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
Oct  8 20:40:39 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.170020] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 69A0 (len 254, WS 0, PS 4) @ 0x69AE
Oct  8 20:40:39 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.170705] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 630C (len 78, WS 12, PS 8) @ 0x6345
Oct  8 20:40:39 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.176742] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:1901 = 261ad03/e
Oct  8 20:40:39 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.176744] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
Oct  8 20:40:39 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.454620] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.593576] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.601065] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.601152] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.601154] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0x00000000130f71f9
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.601155] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0x00000000679535f7
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.601156] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0x00000000343676ec
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.601156] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0x000000003fe861e0
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1801.601157] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0x000000001a688652
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1802.029891] [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xCAFEDEAD)
Oct  8 20:40:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1802.030738] [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
```

### dmesg shows

```
[  153.936921] [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
[  153.936983] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 69A0 (len 254, WS 0, PS 4) @ 0x69AE
[  153.937010] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 630C (len 78, WS 12, PS 8) @ 0x6345
[  153.942315] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:1901 = 261ad03/e
[  153.942317] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
[  154.222946] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
[  154.363113] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
[  154.370596] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[  154.370687] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[  154.370689] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0x00000000ae84d697
[  154.370690] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0x00000000c86ba01c
[  154.370690] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0x000000003d0a11af
[  154.370691] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0x0000000055de998a
[  154.370692] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0x000000002f6275c7
[  154.804875] [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[  154.804908] [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
```

### sudo lshw -c video Shows

```
  *-display                 
       description: Display controller
       product: Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:df200000-df23ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df240000-df25ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

### vgaswitcheroo not working

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
root@ubuntu:~# sudo echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
root@ubuntu:~# sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
root@ubuntu:~# sudo echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
root@ubuntu:~# sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
root@ubuntu:~# sudo echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
root@ubuntu:~# sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
root@ubuntu:~# sudo echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
root@ubuntu:~# sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

Comment: From doing a lot of reading around, looks like the AMD Chipset is not supported as the AMD drivers were dropped in 16-04


* https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
* http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Possibly relates to [this issue](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/linux/commit/?h=drm-fixes-5.0&id=450d007d199e632a1a4c4b91302deacd7d56815f) fixed in [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10813959/).

Upgrading to a newer kernel version that includes the `DPM_FLAG_NEVER_SKIP` flag set (or perhaps some other related kernel fixes included) might help.